# Does a final class declaration affect the performance in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, optimization, final, php-8

**Prologue:** There is a discussion whether or not it is a good habit to declare classes as `final` in PHP by default. Personally I tend to trust the developer team and use `final` only in edge situation, e.g. when we decide to use a Singleton pattern and inheritance would break things. It might be a consideration as well when providing code as a 3rd party framework.

However, there are some languages where the `final` keyword gives some performance advantage since late binding can be excluded at compile time already and the code can be translated with immediate addressing or inlining rather than abstraction via dispatch tables.

```
class SomeClass
{
   public function someMethod() {}
}

// vs.

class SomeOtherClass
{
   public final function someFinalMethod() {}
}

// vs.

final class SomeFinalClass
{
   public function someMethod() {}
}
```

Even if it might be micro optimization:
How does the PHP `final` keyword work in the Zend/PHP engine internals? Does it actually affect the performance in some way?

Consider also situations where a class is instanciated only once or many times.

Comment: Since PHP isn’t *typically* compiled as such, I doubt there are any real optimizations happening. As always, write what you mean first and foremost.

Comment: @deceze It's not compiled AOT, however, PHP is compiled at runtime, newer version even as JIT. Compiling does not necessarily mean as complete native machine code.

Comment: Yes, but since it is just compiled on the fly, it’s probably not spending a lot of time on such potential optimizations.

Comment: @deceze That's my thought and thus I'm asking this question about the internals. I guess in PHP the `final` does not have any effect on the performance, however, I do not *know* it.

Answer (score -1):

As this PHP RFC suggests, there are performance improvements when using final class. Because of that, this RFC suggests automatically consider anonymouse classes as final, to be able to allow such optimizations for anonymouse classes:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/final_anonymous_classes

Comment: Please share more details. The RFC states that it **allows** some optimizations, not that they are really performed. Also, this RFC has just been opened, so how could you already know that this has any impact on the performance?